# socket.emit from node.js client to browser client

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to emit a message from the node.js client to the web client. I am assuming this must be done through the server. Any help is appreciated.

The erorr I see in the browser is:

`GET http://10.1.0.47/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1438260260496-8 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

node.js Client:

```
socket.emit('clientMessage', jsonData, 'Pi-Voyager');
```

Server:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

server.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Gulp is starting my app on PORT: ' + port)
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on("connection", function(socket) {

    socket.on('clientMessage', function(jsonData, from) {
        socket.emit('serverMessage', 'Got a message!', jsonData);
        console.log('Data being sent from', from, 'is:\n' + jsonData);
    });

});
```

web client:

```
<body>
    <h1>9.html</h1>
    <div id="messages"></div>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>

        var socket = io.connect("/");

        socket.on("serverMessage", function(msg) {
            document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML += msg + "<br>";
        })

    </script>   
</body>
```

Comment: Do you have a one node.js app as a client, one web app as a client and a node.js server, all separate? Also, you need to post more code, as you are getting errors when connecting, not emitting messages.

Comment: Yes, One node server, one node client, and one web client, all separate. You are right, i updated my code to reflect the more precise issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably having the server listen on port 8080. And I don't think your client connects there. Try changing

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
```

to

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 80;
```

Also, even if you actually connect, you need to get two different sockets - from your web app and node client app. Because currently, you are taking input from a socket and writing it into the same socket - basically an echo server.

From the io.on('connect') callback you get a socket - that is a connection with a SINGLE client. If you write to it, you write to that client, if you receive from it, you receive from that client.
To make an app broadcasting to all clients (like a chat) you can do this.

```
var sockets = [];
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
   sockets.push(socket);
   socket.on('clientMessage', function(jsonData) {
       for(var i = 0, len = sockets.length; i < len; ++i) {
           sockets[i].emit('serverMessage', 'Got a message!', jsonData);
       }
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. The 80 port change allowed me to connect. Can you clarify what you mean by two different sockets though I am confused.